# How translate works in magento

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I am fairly new to magento and wondering how translation works, I can see there are many csv files under locale/XXXX/ folders which mapping English to various languages, but in actual php/xml/phtml how it been used? Could somebody help me out with an example like "Contact Us" in footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Us link in footer comes from a static block, for that you have to create different store views for different stores and specify translations accordingly.

Little more understanding about translations in Magento. 
These are few types of translations in Magento:

1. DB Translation (core_translate table)
2. Theme specific translation file (app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/locale)
3. Module Specific Translation Files (app/locale/**/*.csv)
4. Translation of static block/cms pages.

**DB Translation**

Translations from the core_translate table are basically merged into the translation array just like the theme translations.
Existing keys from the module or theme translations are overwritten by database records, new ones are added.

**Theme Specific Translation**

Have a look at **app/design/frontend/default/themexyz/locale/en_US/translate.csv**
If you apply themexyz theme, your translations will take effect from above mentioned file

**Module Specific Translation**

Files from app/locale/**/*.csv that are referenced from active modules etc/config.xml files are parsed.

```
<!-- Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml -->
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Mage_Catalog>
                <files>
                    <default>Mage_Catalog.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Mage_Catalog>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```

Inside your block/template/model/controller you write something like Mage::helper('module')->__('text to be translated'); to get your text translated. 
You specify the translation under app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv this way "text to be translated","Translation"

**Translation of static block/cms pages**

[Follow this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/multi-store_set_up/how_to_make_multi-lang_cms_pages)

More information: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t